# longer \dashv sign for adjoint functors

Tags: math-mode

I am trying to write the adjoint sign between two functors

[image] But the only thing i found is the command \dashv

[image]

What is the right command in order to produce the first picture's sign?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The `fdsymbol` and `stix` packages provide a macro called `\longdashv`.

Comment: Just for completeness: the `fdsymbol` package is incompatible with the `amssymb` and `amsfonts` packages, and the `stix` package employs Times Roman-style fonts. This may or may not be a problem for your document.

Comment: I've just tried both of the packages and  there is a problem with the word-style. To be honest, i prefer the default settings. Is there any other package?

Comment: Not that I know of. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\newcommand\longdashv{\mathrel{\relbar\mkern-4mu\relbar\mkern-9mu \vcenter{\hbox{$\dashv$}}}}

\begin{document}

\[ mj_{!} \longdashv (-)\Bigr|_{U}
 \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]